# distance formula using integers, problem with space

Tags: java

so i'm a beginner in java and i recently had an assignment to calculate the distance between two integer points using the distance formula. so far I had

```
import java.util.Scanner;
// user inputs two coordinates (x, y) (x2, y2) and program outputs distance
 public class Distance {
  public static void main (String[] args) {
   try (Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in) {
        System.out.println("Input coordinate 1 with a comma and no space.");
        String coord1 = scan.nextLine(); 
        System.out.println("Input coordinate 2");
        String coord2 = scan.nextLine(); 
        coord1 = coord1.trim();
        coord2 = coord2.trim(); 
        int comma1 = coord1.indexOf(",");  
        int comma2 = coord2.indexOf(",");
        String coordX1 = coord1.substring(0, comma1);
        int valueX1 = Integer.parseInt(coordX1); 
        String coordY1 = coord1.substring(comma1 + 1); 
        int valueY1 = Integer.parseInt(coordY1); 
        String coordX2 = coord2.substring(0, comma2); 
        int valueX2 = Integer.parseInt(coordX2); 
        String coordY2 = coord2.substring(comma2 + 1);
        int valueY2 = Integer.parseInt(coordY2); 
        double distance = Math.sqrt(Math.pow(valueX2 - valueX1, 2) + Math.pow(valueY2 - valueY1, 2)); 
        System.out.println(distance); 
  }
 }
}
```

and this program works only because the user doesn't input a space, and when I try adding the .trim to coord1 and coord2 by putting a line beneath it "coord1 = coord1.trim();" and "coord2 = coord2.trim();" I get this error

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: " 0"
    at java.base/java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:67)
    at java.base/java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:654)
    at java.base/java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:786)
    at Avg.main(Avg.java:17)
```

I want to make it so that the system can accept a space, as in math nobody puts coordinates like (x,y) its always (x, y). apologies if my code isnt minimal as i'm just getting started with learning code.

Comment: Please show the code that is actually failing.

Comment: Also, a cleaner way IMO would be to use `String arr1[] = coord1.split(",");`

Comment: @ScaryWombat i edited the original code (i just added coord1 = coord1.trim(); and the coord2 = coord2.trim();

Comment: trim only remove the space at the beginning or at the end. maybe try trim coordY1 and coordY2 instead

Comment: Or another way would be to replace all space in the inputted strings `coord1 = coord1.replace(" ", "");`

Comment: @ScaryWombat thanks! the coord1.replace worked as well! how would i implement the String arr1[] = coord1.split(","); ?

Comment: You could try calling `split("\\s*,\\s*")` on each line of text, to split it into fields.  That expression for the divider will pick up commas with space permitted (and removed) either side of each comma.  Also, I recommend using `Math.hypot` instead of `Math.sqrt` and `Math.pow` - it's more accurate in many cases.

Comment: @zirute try coding a very small program and then debugging it to see the results.  From these baby steps you can make software.

Answer (score 0):

Note that `.trim()` only removes the trailing spaces and it won't remove spaces in between the characters in your String.

There are quite a few ways to remove **all** spaces within your String. One way I usually use is by doing:

```
coord1 = coord1.replaceAll("\\s","");
coord2 = coord2.replaceAll("\\s","");
```

After removing the whitespaces, you can use `.split()` to delimitate the input:

```
String coordX1 = coord1.split(",")[0];
String coordY1 = coord1.split(",")[1];
int valueX1 = Integer.parseInt(coordX1);
int valueY1 = Integer.parseInt(coordY1);
```

Same goes for your `coordX2` and `coordY2`